# Where is ISDeploymentWizard.exe?

Tags: ssis

Need a full path to IsDeploymentWizard.exe for executing commands such as deploying SSIS packages to a server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IsDeploymentWizard.exe is in this path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn
```

Comment: It is not in this path if you have not Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was installed here:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe"